# Setting a variable outside a $.get request, jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to do what should be a simple task and cannot find a solution. I am trying to set a variable named outside of a $.get request but it does appear to be setting.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var totalPages
            var currentPage = 1;
            //this $.get returns a number
            $.get('getTotalPages.php', function(data) {
                totalPages = data;
            });
            //just an example of applying the result to something else
            if (currentPage < totalPages) {
               ... do something...
            }
        });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

$.get() is asynchronous, but it's only shorthand for full $.ajax() function, which you can set to be synchronous and easily retrieve responseText property.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalPages;

  totalPages = $.ajax({
    url: 'getTotalPages.php',
    async: false
  }).responseText;
});
```

Note that synchronous request forces the script to wait on response, so other actions will be disabled while the request is active.

Comment: This is just short hand for using the success handler though and isn't the reason the async was provided in the first place. Not best practices and in an area that has so few to begin with to boot.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a pretty complex paginated result set (long story) into JSON. I simply needed the total number of pages for the paginated results to know when to show or hide the Prev and Next links. The `getTotalPages.php` file returns the total number of pages based on the number of rows in the table and number of rows per page. Would the above be an acceptable solution? Seems to work.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `$.get()` statement is asychronous.  That means it does not complete immediately, yet you are trying to use the totalPages return value immediately.  In fact, you cannot use the data that it returns until the success handler is called.  In your example, you launch the `$.get()` command (which just starts it) and then you immediately use `totalPages`, but `totalPages` has not yet been set because the `$.get()` has not completed yet so the success handler which sets `totalPages` has not yet been called.

Any work that uses the answer from the `$.get()` must be done in the success handler itself (or functions that it calls) because only then do you know that the result is available.

Change your code to this to see it work (assuming your `get()` is actually working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalPages;
    //this $.get returns a number
    $.get('getTotalPages.php', function(data) {
        totalPages = data;
        //just an example of applying the result to something else
        if (currentPage < totalPages) {
           ... do something...
        }
    });
    // code executed here will execute before the $.get() command has completed
});
```

Comment: The changing of text was a bad example, I should have gone into further detail. I need to pass the number of pages (returned by the `$.get`, to an `if...else` further down the line

Comment: You can't code it that way. You have to continue processing of the `$.get()` result from the success handler itself or other functions you call from the success handler.  You have to structure your code to work with asychronous ajax calls.  You can't do sequential programming like you were trying to do with asychronous ajax.

Comment: I modified the code in my answer to show you where the `if` statement has to go.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done when the browser receivers the ajax request back to it. The $.get method tells you this based on the success function

```
$.get(
{
   'url' : 'someUrl.html',
   'success' : function(data)
   {
       totalPages = data;
       if( totalPages == 1 ) //do stuff
       else            // do other stuff
   }
});
```

or just create the function outside and write 'success' : functionName. Either way its gotta be handled, as mentioned above but i didn't see in the code, after the response has come back from the server.